# .parseXML returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to parse a response from a server that is supposed to be xml. I am a complete newb to web development, though I have been trying to pick up javascript as fast as I can for an assignment. I do not have control of the server.

I am using the line:

```
.get(url,null,storeX,"xml")
```

where the function storeX is mostly some troubleshooting code defined defined as:

```
var x = null;
var storeX = function(input) {
    x = input;
    console.log("input");
    console.log(input);
    $xml = $.parseXML(x);
    console.log("parsed input");
    console.log($xml);
    alert($xml);
}
```

The console output (in Chrome) of console.log(input) gives an expandable tree that seems to correspond to this

```
<results api_version="000.089.077">
<errors/>
<find_poi latitude="32.449331" longitude="-81.782748">
<images>
<image camera_number="1" distance="5.1"/>
<image camera_number="2" distance="5.3"/>
<image camera_number="3" distance="2.1"/>
</images>
</find_poi>
</results>
```

except that in the chrome console this all appears under a top level member `<#document>`
(I have simplified the image elements as they are quite verbose, but appear straightforward)

However, the result of `.parseXML($xml)` is null.

I do not seem to get any sort of message about why the parseXML returned null.

How can I troubleshoot this in a way that will help me determine the error, or is there possibly a simple change I need to make to allow me to get a non null result from .parseXML?

Comment: Please learn about making questions readable - especially surprising considering your rep/badges

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the xml wasn't showing up immediately after and was looking at how to correct that when you made your edits.

Comment: Not a problem - remember the preview under the editing textarea is there for a purpose... so you can iron out the formatting before you submit the question

Comment: Now that I do know. :) It just didn't occur to me that xml might not render so I didn't check it. As I said, I really am completely new to web development. I have intentionally not had javascript or even css on my resume for years. I didn't want to be pulled into coding against a browser in javascript. But you know, "the best laid plans..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input`, presumably, contains an object representing *parsed* XML (since jQuery will parse data with the right content-type unless you tell it not to).

You are converting it to text (probably the string `"[object Object]"`) and trying to parse that as if it was XML (which it isn't).